# I am not able to parse using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
<td>
<a name="corner"></a>
<div>
<div style="aaaaa">
<div class="class-a">My name is alis</div>
</div>
<div>
<span><span class="class-b " title="My title"><span>Very Good</span></span> </span>
<b>My Description</b><br />
          My Name is Alis I am a python learner...
        </div>
<div class="class-3" style="style-2 clear: both;">
          alis
        </div>
</div>
<br /></td>
```

I want the description after scraping it:

```
My Name is Alis I am a python learner...
```

I tried a lots of thing but i could not figure it out the best way. Can you guys give the in general solution for this.

Comment: Can you post what you have tried?

Comment: s = 'above posted html' then I do indexing to go to the last </span>. From where i do indexing till the </br> then retrieving 100 digits which is my descrption.

Comment: please put whatever code you have IN the text block of your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup("Your sample html here")
soup.td.div('div')[2].contents[-1]
```

This will return the string you are looking for (the unicode string, with any applicable whitespace, it should be noted).

This works by parsing the html, grabbing the first td tag and its contents, grabbing any div tags within the first div tag, selecting the 3rd item in the list (list index 2), and grabbing the last of its contents.

In BeautifulSoup, there are A LOT of ways to do this, so this answer probably hasn't taught you much and I genuinely recommend you read the tutorial that David suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reading the examples provided in the documentation?  They quick start is located here http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Quick Start

Edit: 
To find

You would load your html up via

```
 from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
 soup = BeautifulSoup("My html here")
 myDiv = soup.find("div", { "class" : "class-a" })
```

Also remember you can do most of this via the python console and then using dir() along with help() walk through what you're trying to do.   It might make life easier on you to try out ipython or perhaps python IDLE which have very friendly consoles for beginners.

Comment: yah..but i could not figure it out that how to caught those text because it have no tag involved directly.

Comment: My Name is Alis I am a python learner...This is the text i have to caught.

Comment: I would recommend you check out rentacoder.com or similar contracting services provider as you're basically asking me to implement the solution vs. you learning how to do it yourself.

Comment: I am not asking you to implement the solution. It is all about to share idea here. If you don't know or don't want to share it is Ok. Thnaks